# https www not able to redirect to non-www https nginx

Tags: nginx, redirect, django

I can't seem to redirect my `https://www` to `https://` How it is currently the site thinks that `www`. is a completely separate site. I want to redirect properly, but when I add configuration on what I think is correct I get an infinite redirect. Non-https www redirects properly. Only issue is `https://www`.

Here is my nginx config, maybe I am just missing something. I removed the `https://www` redirect because I can't seem to get it right.

```
server {
    listen 192.168.0.123:80;
    server_name www.site.com site.com;

    location /rss/main/ {
            uwsgi_pass unix:///tmp/site.com.sock;
            include uwsgi_params;
    }

    location / {
            rewrite ^ https://site.com$request_uri permanent;
    }

}
server {
        listen 192.168.0.123:443 ssl;
        server_name site.com;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/site.com_access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/site.com_error.log;

        ssl_certificate /srv/ssl/site_com.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /srv/ssl/site.com.key;

        location / {
                uwsgi_pass unix:///tmp/site.com.sock;
                include uwsgi_params;
        }

        location /static/ {
                alias /var/www/site.com/static_final/;
        }

        location /media/ {
                alias /var/www/assets/site/;
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated as I don't want people to accidentally access the www.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a simple 301 redirect, we could use [return](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpRewriteModule#return) directive.

```
server {
        listen 192.168.0.123:443 ssl;
        server_name www.site.com;

        ssl_certificate /srv/ssl/site_com.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /srv/ssl/site.com.key;

        return 301 $scheme://site.com$request_uri;
}
```

This is effectively the same as Alan's answer, but [by using the return directive we can completely avoid evaluation of regular expression](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/#taxing-rewrites).

Comment: Both answers worked, but I went with this one.

Answer (score 3):

I assume your SSL certificate covers both www.site.com and site.com.  The following would appear to be the most appropriate way of handling this?

```
server {
        listen 192.168.0.123:443 ssl;
        server_name www.site.com;

        ssl_certificate /srv/ssl/site_com.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /srv/ssl/site.com.key;

        rewrite ^ https://site.com$request_uri permanent;
}
```